# How to get Contents of text files as value in foreach loop in glob function in php?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am developing a search engine with vector space Model. I successfully computed tf-idf with associative array data already define in code. Now I want that data should be come from directory where I have a folders and in each folder there is a number of text files with dummy data. I have tried alot but stuck at 1 point using **glob** function because I want all **.txt** files as **key** and its contents as **value** in foreach loop of glob function.... Below is my code.

**Tf-idf With Associative Array Data**

```
$collection = array(
1 => 'this string is a short string but a good string',
2 => 'this one isn\'t quite like the rest but is here',
3 => 'this is a different short string that\' not as short'
);

$dictionary = array();
$docCount = array();

foreach($collection as $docID => $doc) {
    $terms = explode(' ', $doc);
    $docCount[$docID] = count($terms);

    foreach($terms as $term) {
        if(!isset($dictionary[$term])) {
            $dictionary[$term] = array('df' => 0, 'postings' => array());
        }
        if(!isset($dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID])) {
            $dictionary[$term]['df']++;
            $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID] = array('tf' => 0);
        }

        $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID]['tf']++;
    }
}

$temp = ('docCount' => $docCount, 'dictionary' => $dictionary);
```

As you see in 1st **foreach loop** is that **$DocID** is key and **$doc** is its contents(value) of collection array. But I don't know how to implement exact same thing when files read from directory. See code below..

**Tf-idf With .txt Files and its contents read from directory**

```
foreach (glob("C:\\wamp\\www\\Web-info\\documents\\awd_1990_00\\*.txt") as $file) {
    $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
    //echo $file;
    $dictionary = array();
    $docCount = array();

    foreach($file as $docID=> $value) {
        echo $value;
        $terms = explode(' ', $doc);
        $docCount[$docID] = count($terms);

        foreach($terms as $term) {
            if(!isset($dictionary[$term])) {
                $dictionary[$term] = array('df' => 0, 'postings' => array());
            }
            if(!isset($dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID])) {
                $dictionary[$term]['df']++;
                $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID] =     array('tf' => 0);
            }

            $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID]['tf']++;
        }
    }
}
$temp = array('docCount' => $docCount, 'dictionary' => $dictionary);
```

This gives me **error** on 1st foreach loop that **invalid arugument supplied for foreach loop**. As I mentioned earlier I want .txt files as a **key** and its contents as a **value** in 1st **foreach loop**. But I got this error Can anybody please Tell me how to do this.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. `$file` is just a filename, what are you looping over in the `foreach`? If you want to loop over the lines, use `while ($line = fgets($file_handle)`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for reply. I am trying that filenames should get as key and its contents as value in 1st foreach loop as its my requirements and don't need another while loop to get its contents. All the contents should get in glob function. is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat the entire file as one value, you can use `file_get_contents()` to read the file into a string:

```
$dictionary = array();
$docCount = array();
foreach (glob("C:\\wamp\\www\\Web-info\\documents\\awd_1990_00\\*.txt") as $docID) {
    $value = file_get_contents($docID);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar Now I get the files contents as value But still 1 problem left is that I want file names as key instead of numbers ([0],[1],[2] etc..) I want like this ([1.txt]=>its content,[2.txt]=> its content etc)... Thanks alot for your reply.

Comment: You can't repeat the same key in an array. All the lines in the file have the same filename.

Comment: i want to get an array of document with its content
array (){[1] contnet of document, [2] content of 2nd document ........}

Comment: Please update the question and show what you're trying to get. It's not very clear. Before you said you didn't want numeric keys, now it looks like you do.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. Your Updated code did not make the array of file and its contents and gives the same error that Invalid argument supplied for foreach loop. I want the array of doument with its contents Like [1] => content of 1st document [2] => content of 2nd document etc. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: I give up. You said you wanted the keys to be the file names. Now you say you want `[1] => contents`. That's not a file name.

Comment: I've shown you two ways to do it because you weren't clear in the question. Surely you should be able to get the general idea from these answers and figure out how to do what you really want. I don't understand why you're getting invalid argument in foreach loop. As long as the argument is an array it should work. You need to know when you have arrays and when you have strings, how hard is that?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for your valuable time and help. Just tell me how to update foreach loop according to your updated answer because in your updated answer you did not mention foreach loop.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `foreach(glob() as $filename)` to loop over the files. If you use `$lines = file($filename)` you can use `foreach($lines as $line)` to loop over the lines in a file. You can nest one inside the other to loop over all the files and then loop over the lines in the file. Then you can make a multidimensional array -- the first dimension is keyed by filenames, the second is keyed by line number in the file.